# How to Check a Process is Running on Another Server

Tags: linux, shell-script, process-management

How do I go about checking that a certain process is running in another box and return a value? For example, if I wanted to check that process 'FTP' is running in 192.168.1.1 from box 192.168.1.2, how would I return a success flag? I would like to incorporate a script that would check a certain process is running within a cluster of servers.

I tried to come up with something without much success:

```
for i in 'cat server_list.txt';
     do ssh $i
          "ps -ef | grep ftp = process;
          if [ $process -eq 1]
              then 
                  echo "ftp process is running"
          fi"
```

I would like to have a return letting me know that the 'ftp' process is running. There are a list of servers IP in the server list text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r host; do
   if ssh -n "$host" "pgrep '^ftp$'"; then
      echo "A process named 'ftp' is running on ${host}."
   fi
done < /path/to/server_list
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to return anything even if the process is running

Comment: Wouldn't that `ssh` consume all input on standard in, thus emptying the list of hosts past the first?

Comment: @thrig you are right, I fixed my edit

Comment: @keyboard_solo the answer this provides only matches *exactly* "ftp". You may want to remove the `^$` anchors and/or add `-f` to pgrep.

Comment: I put those in so as to match the exact process name specified in the question.  Otherwise, it would false-positive on e. g. `ftpd`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti as a side note, you can use `-x` for exact matches instead of anchoring.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  When I see "grep", I just automatically start thinking in regular expressions; hence the anchors.